# Python/Telethon как скачивать только фото, а не все файлы подряд?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Всем привет. Делаю бота на python с telethon. Нужно скачать фото на сервер для последующей обработки. Нашел в нете подходящий скрипт. Проблема в том, что он скачивает с канала не только фото, но и громоздкие видео. **Как скачивать только фото?** Думаю, что есть для этого специализированная команда, но в документации я не смог ее найти или понять. Еще как вариант установить проверку файла перед скачиванием, что файл именно фото. Опыта мало, поэтому еще не знаю как это сделать. Подскажите, кто знает.

```
with TelegramClient('name', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
        offset_date=None,
        offset_id=0,
        offset_peer="username",
        limit=500,
        hash=0,
    ))

    title = 'Новинки Margaret❤'
    for chat in result.chats:
        print(chat)

        if chat.title == title:
            messages = client.get_messages(chat, limit=1000)

            for message in tqdm(messages):
                message.download_media('./' + title + '/')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, нужно сделать проверку на тип медиавложения.

```
for message in tqdm(messages):
    if type(message.media) == telethon.MessageMediaPhoto: #является ли тип вложения сообщения фотографией
        message.download_media('./' + title + '/')
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.